# ActionPrevious getting an unexpected background

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I've made a rule in my kv for the `Button` class to have a specific background (provided in an image). When I created an `ActionBar` that contains `ActionPrevious` and `ActionButton` widgets, they both seemed to get the same background.
And I would understand that `ActionButton` instance got that background, since it inherits from `Button` and `ActionItem` classes, but why did the `ActionPrevious` get the same background? It inherits from `BoxLayout` and `ActionItem`, neither of which have anything to do with the `Button` class. What's the reason behind it?

Also, a side question
The `ActionPrevious` has a property `with_previous` which, when set to `True`, adds a clickable arrow. However, the title of the widget remains unclickable. But the docs say that this property would make the whole widget clickable. While it's not a big deal, I'd rather want the entire `ActionPrevious` widget background to change on press. Is it possible to achieve this?
So what I mean is that when you press the Back arrow, only the space around it and the app icon turns blue, but the text doesn't, as if it's part of a different widget.

Here is the code to visualize the question:

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.actionbar import ActionBar

Builder.load_string('''
<Button>:
    background_normal: 'some_file.png'

<MenuBar>:
    ActionView:
        ActionPrevious:
            title: "Log out"
            with_previous: True
        ActionButton:
            text: "Settings"
''')
class MenuBar(ActionBar):
    pass

runTouchApp(MenuBar())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the truth was in the `style.kv` file. Basically, `ActionPrevious` widget has the following structure:

```
<ActionPrevious>:
    GridLayout:
        ActionPreviousButton:
            GridLayout:
                ActionPreviousImage:
                    id: prev_icon_image  # the "back" arrow
                ActionPreviousImage:
                    id: app_icon_image   # the app icon
                Widget:
                    # perhaps something to split the title from the GridLayout
    Label:
        id: title                        # the title
```

And the `ActionPreviousButton` inherits from `Button`, so that's why the `ActionPrevious` arrow part was getting that background.

Here also lies the answer to the side question. Since the clickable part is the `ActionPreviousButton`, and the title is kept in a `Label`, that is not a child of it, the text is unclickable. So to fix that, one has to create a custom class and put the `Label` as a child of the `ActionPreviousButton`.