# How to move a widget that was defined in kv around the tree?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

In pursuit of making the title text of the `ActionPrevious` clickable (more about it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724426/actionprevious-getting-an-unexpected-background)), I'm trying to modify the default widget tree defined in the [`style.kv`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/data/style.kv#L602) file. My attempt was to access the widgets by id during the `__init__`. This is what my subclass looks like:

```
class LogoutButton(ActionPrevious):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LogoutButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print(self.children)      # prints an empty tuple
        print(self.ids)           # prints an empty dictionary
        lb = self.ids['title']
        self.remove_widget(lb)
        self.ids['prevlayout'].add_widget(lb)
```

So, those prints show that there aren't any children during the `__init__`, even though I called the ActionPrevious's `__init__` already.
I know that what I'm trying to achieve can be accomplished by just copying the entire definition and adjusting the indentation, but it seems a little too large and I don't want to have such a thing in my code. Can I do the same using a subclass and Python without copying the kv definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read `ids` or `children` table, you should wait until the second kivy's loop frame. Here, you are trying to access them in the first loop frame, before they are put together into a widget tree.

What you should do is to wait until the first frame ends, and then read the values. The easiest way to do this is to use the [`@mainthread`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.mainthread) decorator. Example:

```
from kivy.clock import mainthread

class LogoutButton(ActionPrevious):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LogoutButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.do_something()

    @mainthread
    def do_something(self):
        print(self.children)
        print(self.ids)
        lb = self.ids['title']
        self.remove_widget(lb)
        self.ids['prevlayout'].add_widget(lb)
```